# Incorrect syntax in trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables called account and transaction. I need to insert data to transaction automatically when account inserts data. I created this trigger in MySQL. It gives error 1064 (Syntax error). What is the problem?

```
CREATE TRIGGER upTransaction AFTER INSERT ON account FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO transaction VALUES (2,account.openDate,CURTIME(),
    account.deposit,account.accNo,
    "Teller","Cash","Deposit");
END
```

Comment: I guess that you change the delimiter, right?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Your tags and syntax seem to conflict. [tag:sql-server] is for Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL gets confused with semicolons inside the BEGIN END block, so you must use DELIMITER to temporarily force MySQL to use a different delimiter.
Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER upTransaction AFTER INSERT ON account FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO transaction VALUES (2,account.openDate,CURTIME(),account.deposit,account.accNo,"Teller","Cash","Deposit");
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

You probably need to replace:

```
      INSERT INTO transaction VALUES (2,account.openDate,CURTIME(),account.deposit,account.accNo,"Teller","Cash","Deposit");
```

with:

```
      INSERT INTO transaction VALUES (2,NEW.openDate,CURTIME(),NEW.deposit,NEW.accNo,"Teller","Cash","Deposit");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is you original trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER upTransaction AFTER INSERT ON account FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO transaction VALUES (2,account.openDate,CURTIME(),
    account.deposit,account.accNo,
    "Teller","Cash","Deposit");
END
```

Replace `account.` with `NEW.` (optional : replace `"` with `'`)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER upTransaction AFTER INSERT ON account FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO transaction VALUES (2,NEW.openDate,CURTIME(),
    NEW.deposit,NEW.accNo,
    'Teller','Cash','Deposit');
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE
TRIGGER `event_name` AFTER INSERT
ON `database`.`table`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    -- trigger body
    -- this code is applied to every
    -- inserted/updated/deleted row
END;
```

Seems like you're missing a table name after 'account'. (edit: or a database name before account, I'm not certain as to what account pertains to)

Comment: The database name is optional when using CREATE TRIGGER.